# a question about the UIAlertView

Tags: selector, uialertview

all

it will show a UIAlertView when i click a button on the view

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
initWithTitle: @"Will you?" 
message:@"will you go there?"
delegate:self
cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
otherButtonTitles:@"Yes" nil];
```

i want to give two selector to the two button,when i click the 'NO' button,do nothing,but just close this alertview,if i click the Yes button,that means i choose a selector called 'donextthing' , so how can i do?thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your .h add the **UIAlertViewDelegate**, something like this:

```
@interface yourView : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

And in your .m add this after your **UIAlertView**:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *alertIndex = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([alertIndex isEqualToString:@"Yes"])
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```